# Suppress "Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y'" rule

Tags: typescript

```
[1] Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.  TS2339
```

How does one suppress this in `tsconfig`? I have been reading the https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html page, but nothing seems obvious.

Comment: You *shouldn't* suppress the whole family of these checks. If you do, you may as well ditch TS altogether as you're removing one of the core reasons to use TS in the first place. Instead, you should make sure you don't get any random HTML element but actually one with `value`.

Comment: @VLAZ We do use TypeScript, however for other convenient things. We do not wish to use this core feature.

Comment: You don't use **Type**Script for **type** checking?

Comment: Is HTMLElement your own type?

Comment: @VLAZ Exactly! :)